# How can I calculate the next birthday programmatically

Tags: vb.net

I have a data table with a date-of-birth column.

I would want to split the date apart and change the year part with today.year which is current year.

Below is my code:

```
Dim birthda As New SqlDataAdapter(birthcmd)
Dim birthdt As New DataTable
birthda.Fill(birthdt)

For Each rw As DataRow In birthdt.Rows
    Dim dob As String = rw.Item(3)

    Dim mdat As Date = FormatDateTime(dob, DateFormat.ShortDate)

    Dim bday As Date = (Date.Today.Year & mdat.Month & mdat.Day)

    Dim yers As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, mdat.Date, Today.Date)
    Dim moths As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, mdat.Date, Today.Date)
    Dim dys As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, mdat.Date, Today.Date)
```

but I get this error:

> **Conversion from string "2019715" to type 'Date' is not valid.**
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "2019715" to type 'Date' is not valid.
>
> Source Error:
>   Line 149:
>   Line 150:            Dim bday As Date = (Date.Today.Year & mdat.Month & mdat.Day)

Comment: Read about the parseable format here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/date-data-type . Also, consider using .NET DateTime instead of Date.

Comment: 1) What is the type of the column in the database? (Is it a varchar, a datetime, or something else?) 2) What do you want to happen if the date of birth falls on the 29th February but the year you're calculating for is not a leap year?

Comment: the column is datetime and would want to check those who have upcoming birthdays for a particular week so the dys2 in my code if the value falls between 1 and 7 then that is it

Answer (score 0):

VB.net is very peculiar when it comes to String to Date conversion.

I would recommend converting the Date from the individual components like this :

```
Dim bday as Date = New Date(Date.Today.Year, mdat.Month, mdat.Day)
```

Or as stated in the comments try using VB.Net DateTime

```
Dim bday as New DateTime(Date.Today.Year, mdat.Month, mdat.Day, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: I tried that but now get this error Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.

Comment: @mcvision Can you paste the exact code you are using?

Comment: thank you i think I have figured it out this is what i did. I calculated for the age with respect to current year and added the result to the year part of the date of birth.

Answer (score 0):

thank you i think I have figured it out this is what i did. I calculated for the age with respect to current year and added the result to the year part of the date of birth.
here is the code

For Each rw As DataRow In birthdt.Rows

```
        Dim dob As DateTime = rw.Item(2)


        Dim mdat As Date = FormatDateTime(dob, DateFormat.ShortDate)

     Dim yers As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, mdat.Date, Today.Date)
        Dim moths As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, mdat.Date, Today.Date)

        Dim dys As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, mdat.Date, Today.Date)

        Dim ndob As Date = (DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, yers, mdat))

        Dim yers2 As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, ndob.Date, Today.Date)
        Dim moths2 As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, ndob.Date, Today.Date)
        Dim dys2 As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, ndob.Date, Today.Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am basing this on what you wrote in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58198707/how-can-i-calculate-the-next-birthday-programatically#comment102788991_58198707):

> want to check those who have upcoming birthdays for a particular week.

It is fiddly to deal with leap years and dates which might be in the next year, but I think I've got all the cases covered here.

I made a table "Pets" in SQL Server with columns "Name" and "DOB", and put some data in.

I made a new Windows Forms project and added a multi-line textbox to Form1, and used this code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1

    Sub ShowUpcomingBirthdays()
        Dim csb As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder With {.DataSource = ".\SQLEXPRESS", .InitialCatalog = "Testing", .IntegratedSecurity = True}

        Dim birthdt As New DataTable()

        Dim sql = "SELECT [Name], [DOB] FROM [Pets]"

        Using conn As New SqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString)
            Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter With {.SelectCommand = sqlCmd}
                da.Fill(birthdt)
            End Using
        End Using

        Dim matchEarliest = DateTime.Today
        Dim matchLatest = matchEarliest.AddDays(8)

        Dim sb As New StringBuilder ' somewhere to save the matching data

        For Each r As DataRow In birthdt.Rows
            Dim dob = Convert.ToDateTime(r.Item("DOB"))

            ' Allow for leap years by transferring the birthday to 1st March - some countries would use 28th February.
            If DateTime.IsLeapYear(dob.Year) AndAlso Not DateTime.IsLeapYear(matchEarliest.Year) AndAlso dob.Month = 2 AndAlso dob.Day = 29 Then
                dob = dob.AddDays(1)
            End If

            Dim nextBirthday = New DateTime(matchEarliest.Year, dob.Month, dob.Day)

            If dob.Month <= matchEarliest.Month AndAlso dob.Day < matchEarliest.Day Then
                ' birthday has already happened this calendar year, make it next year
                nextBirthday = nextBirthday.AddYears(1)
            End If

            If nextBirthday >= matchEarliest AndAlso nextBirthday < matchLatest Then
                ' the record is in the required range
                sb.AppendLine(CStr(r.Item("Name")) & " " & dob.ToString("ddd dd MMMM"))
            End If

        Next

        TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ShowUpcomingBirthdays()

    End Sub

End Class
```

It includes birthdays which happen "today" (you might not want to miss that), but you could

```
        Dim matchEarliest = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)
        Dim matchLatest = matchEarliest.AddDays(7)
```

if you didn't want to include today.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little class called Employee (it is at the bottom of the code). This answer is a bit similar to @AndrewMorton. I broke up the Sub into several functions that can be altered to suit without breaking the rest.

```
Private Sub DisplayUpcomingBirthdays()
    Dim lstBirthdays As New List(Of Employee)
    Dim dt = RetrieveBirthdays()
    For Each rw As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim CurrentYearBirthday As Date = GetCurrentYearBD(CDate(rw.Item("Birthdate")))
        If IsBDThisWeek(CurrentYearBirthday) Then
            lstBirthdays.Add(New Employee(CurrentYearBirthday, rw.Item("Name").ToString))
        End If
    Next
    Dim SortedList = SortByBirthdays(lstBirthdays)
    ListBox1.DataSource = SortedList
End Sub

Private Function RetrieveBirthdays() As DataTable
    Dim query = "Select Name, Birthdate From Employes;"
    Dim birthdt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("YourConnectionString")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query, cn)
            cn.Open()
            birthdt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return birthdt
End Function

Private Function GetCurrentYearBD(BirthDate As Date) As Date
    Dim Day As Integer = BirthDate.Day
    Dim Month As Integer = BirthDate.Month
    Dim Year As Integer = Now.Year
    'Bithday is celebrated on the 28th when it is not a leap year
    If Month = 2 AndAlso Day = 29 AndAlso Not DateTime.IsLeapYear(Year) Then
        Day = 28
    End If
    Return New DateTime(Year, Month, Day)
End Function

Private Function IsBDThisWeek(BD As Date) As Boolean
    Dim Tomorow = Now.AddDays(1)
    Dim WeekFromNow = Now.AddDays(7)
    If BD >= Tomorow AndAlso BD <= WeekFromNow Then
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function

Private Function SortByBirthdays(Employees As List(Of Employee)) As List(Of Employee)
    Dim lst = (From emp In Employees
               Order By emp.Birthdate
               Select emp).ToList
    Return lst
End Function

Public Class Employee
    Public Property Birthdate As Date
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Sub New(BD As Date, eName As String)
        Birthdate = BD
        Name = eName
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{Name},  {Birthdate.ToString("MMMM dd")}"
    End Function
End Class
```